# DBwrite Table Error in R MYSQL-UTF 8

Tags: r, utf-8, rmysql, rsqlite

I have the following dataframe

```
df<-data.frame(
  SLNO=c(1:5),
  sentence=c("Campaign Blast all channels Team may8t", "MDC Email Campaign 1 on  june 13", "Email camp Blastteam 09","Email camp Blastteam 09", "Email camp Blastteam 09thcamp"
)
```

I am writing the dataframe to an SQL Table using the following code

```
    require(rmysql)
    require(rsqlite)
    name<-'username'
    password<-'userpass'
    hostname<-'1.2.3.4'
    port<-2222
    database<-'db'
    connection1<-dbConnect(dbDriver("MySQL"), user=username, 
      password=userpass, dbname= db, host=hostname, port=port)
```

The table I am writing to already exists in the database db- table

```
       dbWriteTable(custdbconn, value = df,
         name ='table' , overwrite=F, append=T,
         field.types=list(SlNo= 'int()', Sentence= 'text'), row.names=F)
```

I am getting an error that says

```
     Invalid utf8 character string: 'MDC Email Campaign 1 on
```

If i individually insert the rows, the rows write to the SQL database.
Is there a way to write this entire table without the error showing up.

Comment: Don't use `<-` inside column assignment of `data.frame`, it's not the same as `=` here. (Notice how the column names are not preserved? That's one sign it's not ideal.) Second: I recommend against the use of `require` like this; the only reason you should ever use `require` is if you capture its return value and do something based on it (refs: https://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/ and http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#search-path).

Comment: yes Sir. I noted it

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite elegant and simple

```
   Encoding(df$sentence)<-"UTF-8"
```

This has solved the issue